# Website is getting an error message: mysqli_real_connect() and mysql_connect()

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have been trying to access the file manager of `OVH` and have been trying to use `FileZilla`, which didn't work. However, the big problem is that I am now getting this error message:

```
Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'thebalk41'@'10.0.13.59' (using password: YES) in XXX.fr/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1531

Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in XXXfr/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1562

Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'thebalk41'@'10.0.13.59' (using password: YES) in XXX.fr/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1562
```

(I have replaced the website with XXX).

However, since I can't access the files of the website, I can't access the `MySQL` files. Can someone help me with what is going on?

Thank you!

Comment: You have multiple issues here. Your mysql credentials are incorrect and you are mixing mysql APIs. Also, none of this has anything to do with FTP so I am unsure why you can't access the files on the website.

Comment: For starters, you can ditch that mysql_connect deprecation issue by using mysqli_connect. Then contact your team for the proper credentials, as John C. suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, all fixed. Problem was that the password of the sql database had been changed on the server side but not on the wp-config.php one. Had to retrieve the former password and update it. Now everything is working. Thanks again!